2010 Hyundai Santa Fe push button start no accessories or ignition
I have a 2010 Hyundai Santa Fe Highlander with push button start. Suddenly it won't turn accessories on (without brake pressed) or start (with brake pressed). Gear shifter is in park. There is nothing on the dash. No lights, no message on the screen saying key not found or anything like that.
If I unplug the steering lock sensor a message will appear on screen telling me to check the steering lock.
The door makes a binging noise when I open it, every time, which stops when I push the start button.
I can't connect my scanner as I can't get accessories/ ignition to power on. I've checked all the fuses both visually and continuity. I've replaced the push button. I've checked all the connectors on the bcm and pdm under the dash as well as on the fuse box. I've check battery and ground connections.
I'm at a loss of what else to try or what it could be that would even prevent the accessories from turning on.

Have you checked the voltage at the battery?

Yes. The battery is fine. Fully charged, no dropped cells

A14 yr old vehicle may have age related issues. While battery connections are suspect from corrosion interfering with good electrical connections, battery grounds may be overlooked between battery and chassis and chassis to engine block. Be sure battery terminals are clean and free from died battery acid,  using a warm water solution of baking soda to immediately dissolve and neutralize dried battery acid residues. An old toothbrush works. Rinse with plain water. Examine negative connections to chassis and engine block too.

I've cleaned and checked battery terminals as well as checked the ground connections and made sure they are clean and properly connected.

Have you looked at the wiring with the starter motor?
